# make and ">" redirector not working as expected in gnome-terminal

Tags: shell, cmake, makefile, gnome-terminal

For an operating systems class I am taking at university, I am required to work on a large teaching operating system. The code I'm working on has been provided with a bunch of makefiles and is compiled with `cmake` and `make`.

Since there are a bunch of warnings (which I'd like to get rid of) in the code and the build tree is quite big, I'm trying to redirect the build log to a file with `make > output.txt`.

However, this only writes the output from `make` to the file:

`output.txt` looks like this:

```
[ 63%] Building CXX object common/source/kernel/CMakeFiles/common_kernel.dir/Syscall.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object common/source/kernel/CMakeFiles/common_kernel.dir/Thread.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object common/source/kernel/CMakeFiles/common_kernel.dir/TimeManager.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object common/source/kernel/CMakeFiles/common_kernel.dir/UserProcess.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object common/source/kernel/CMakeFiles/common_kernel.dir/UserThread.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../../lib/libcommon_kernel.a
```

Output from gcc or g++ however is still printed to the shell like this:

```
In file included from /home/user/Desktop/bs2015G07/userspace/tests/x7_cancellation_points.c:4:0:
/home/user/Desktop/bs2015G07/userspace/tests/../libc/include/stdlib.h:90:22: warning: ‘start’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static mem_block_t * start;
                      ^
/home/user/Desktop/bs2015G07/userspace/tests/x7_cancellation_points.c: In function ‘function’:
/home/user/Desktop/bs2015G07/userspace/tests/x7_cancellation_points.c:14:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

Is there a way to redirect all output to one single file? 
Or is there a way to somehow enlarge the shell text buffer, so I could view all output on the shell?

Comment: You probably need to redirect stderr, too: `make 2> output.txt > output.txt`. (I’m not sure whether that works when they’re both the same file, though. `make 2>&1 | tee output.txt`?)

Comment: bash-specific I believe syntax for this is: `make &> output.txt` or more portably: `make > output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @minitech: `make 2> output.txt > output.txt` did write to the same file, but the part caused by make was first and the gcc/g++ part second. The second command worked perfectly however. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Etan `make &> output.txt` worked perfectly fine, I'm going to use this. Thank you very much.

Comment: `make 2> output.txt > output.txt` should have given you the same output in the file as `make > output.txt` I believe but <shrug>.

Answer (score 2):

This will write all output (stderr and stdout) to file:

```
command > file 2>&1
```